# Issue with Cordova 3.0.0 facebook-connect plugin add in Sencha touch 2.3

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

I am working with Cordova Facebook connect plugin in Sencha touch 2.3, app works good when I add Facebook plugin manually in iOS and android. But I want to add Facebook-connect plugin using cordova plugin add ........... so that it will install both in iOS and Android. After installing cordova Facebook plugin and trying to build sencha app using sencha app build native,I am getting the error saying APP_ID and APP_NAME not found. Is there a way to add APP_ID and APP_NAME in plugin.xml file ?? can anyone please help me on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a plugin that is compatible with Cordova 3.0.0 and can install in Sencha touch locally .. here is the plugin

https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin

this is working great after little fixes.

This can be added in Sencha cordova plugins using following command

cordova local plugin add https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="[FB APP ID]" --variable APP_NAME="[FB APP NAME]"

Comment: I tried to install the plugin but it always says missing variables. I did basically the same thing.

Comment: Hi GiGi, can you share some of the code how you initialized FB with this SDK?

Comment: What version od cordova are you using ?  Me got errors after some cordova updates so I started installing manually in iOS and Android after building it.

Comment: I'm using Phonegap 3.4.0-0.19.8. So did you end up using this plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin? Sencha touch command line tool will generate a Xcode project for us, right? But the code is compressed, and I don't know how to install the plugin for it. Did you just put the original code of your sencha project in Cordova project?

Comment: Yes I am using  github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin, from sencha you build for iOS and Android using "sencha app build native" from terminal, then you go to the cordova/platforms/ios/ and you find the built project,open it in Xcode and then follow the same steps to install it manually. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova follow this on how to include cordova in Sencha.

Comment: Yeah I understand the steps. But a problem I'm thinking about is that actually I need the user's Facebook info such as his/her name. I've implemented this in Sencha Touch in Javascript with Facebook's official JS SDK. So my question is if you manually installed the plugin in XCode project, how did you integrate it with your Sencha code which should be compressed in the XCode project?

Comment: Add those js files in one folder and add that path in extras : {} in app.js file, so that you can update js files you can see the results. Refer those js files in index.html . This should be one way to do testing easily in Xcode.

Comment: Hi GiGi, can you kindly provide an example or write a tutorial about this? I've been stuck at this for long. Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by those js files? Shall I put all the js code that depends on Facebook in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
  <param name="APP_ID" value="..." />
  <param name="APP_NAME" value="..." />
</gap:plugin>
```

in your config.xml?

This is supposed to pick up the most recent versions.

Comment: Thank you , I am trying to install it from Sencha app after initializing cordova ,  using the following cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect.git --variable APP_ID="00000000000000" --variable APP_NAME="SampleApp" but this is not working ... I am getting Error fetching plugin: Error: Error, is there any way to install it using cordova plugin add or am I need to add manually.